# React fundamentals. Lifecycle method for initial data fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The official React docs says that you should fetch data from server in [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#where-in-the-component-lifecycle-should-i-make-an-ajax-call) lifecycle method.

It could sound a bit weird that in case when your component need some data (which is pretty often) you should always wait for initial rendering, including slow DOM api manipulations for the component and its children. It provides unreasonable delay in sending the request to server.

How could you explain why it is a good decision for React team not to implement a special lyfecycle method like componentFetchInitialData (which is invoked at the beginning) for initial data fetching?

> The question from the interview that made me confused

Comment: This probably could be because of considering the general use case API calling is done. When you are working with React you manage data via `state` of the component. And there is often a case that when you bring that data from the API you'll set the data in the state, which eventually is used to show the UI dynamically.

Comment: This is a tricky question. It's NOT a good decision but just a legacy of React synchronous renderer (which corresponds to now dated class components and mentioned lifecycle hooks). This has been solved with proprietary hooks in Next.js. Vue (which heavily borrows from React) has been successfully implemented suspense feature and async components that are similar to React's suspense that's still experimental and not much usable afaik. This may be not a good idea to block a render of the whole component tree with a single request, but that's for a dev to decide, not a framework

Comment: That's for a hook that could block rendering when fetching data. For a hook that doesn't block rendering but just starts to fetch asap the answer is much simpler. There's been componentWillMount that allowed to fire requests a bit earlier while not waiting for them, but this happened at the expense of delayed initial render. It's been deprecated because it's massively misused AND doesn't play well with new renderer's concurrent mode that allows to throw unmounted component instance to garbage. I guess a good answer should cover both parts